# thread local storage duration before thread join

Tags: c, gcc, pthreads

Is thread local storage (C11's _Thread_local or gcc's __thread) still available after (non-detached) thread returns, but before it is joined (eg. accessed through pointer from other thread)?

Comment: It is not safe to rely on such post-termination accesses with either flavor of thread-local storage.  Thread locals' lifetimes end when execution of their thread terminates, regardless of whether or when that thread is joined.

Answer (score 2):

In case of `gcc`'s `__thread`, it's valid to access from any thread, [Thread-Local Storage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Thread-Local.html):

> When the address-of operator is applied to a thread-local variable, it
> is evaluated at run time and returns the address of the current
> thread’s instance of that variable. An address so obtained may be used
> by any thread. When a thread terminates, any pointers to thread-local
> variables in that thread become invalid.

It's implementation defined in C11.

§ 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects ([N2176.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf)):

> An object whose identifier is declared with the storage-class
> specifier _Thread_local has thread storage duration. Its lifetime is
> the entire execution of the thread for which it is created, and its
> stored value is initialized when the thread is started. There is a
> distinct object per thread, and use of the declared name in an
> expression refers to the object associated with the thread evaluating
> the expression. The result of attempting to indirectly access an
> object with thread storage duration from a thread other than the one
> with which the object is associated is implementation-defined.

---

The above answers whether accessing thread local variable(s) of a thread from other thread(s) while the owner thread is alive. As both quotes say accessing them *after* the thread terminates is invalid.

So the question becomes when does a thread really terminate and whether a thread can be considered "alive" after returning from thread function but before it may have been *joined*.

Both POSIX and C11's `thrd_exit` say that the calling thread terminates when it calls `pthread_exit`/`thrd_exit` or does a `return`. So the lifetime of the thread local objects end at that point - meaning it's no longer valid to access them.

Comment: The question is whether thread B can access thread A's threadlocals *after A terminates* (but before it is joined).  Regardless of whether you can do so while thread A is running, I think both flavors agree that an attempt to do so after thread A terminates reaps undefined behavior.  Whether  thread A has been joined is not directly relevant.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for calling it out - I have amended the answer now.